# Dual booting issues, windows 8, 12.10, eufi

Tags: 12.10, uefi, boot-repair

I just purchased a Windows 8 desktop and set about installing ubuntu.  The installer couldn't read the hdd, so I installed ubuntu to a separate drive.  Now I can't boot into windows, says grub can't find the path, and the only way to boot into ubuntu is to keep the usb stick in, I assume the EFI partition is on the stick, but I've tried installing it to the drive and haven't found any success.  I ran boot repair, says all is good, but the problem persists.  I've tried googling for a similar problem and have come up empty handed.  Any suggestions?

**edit: boot repair got ubuntu to boot with the usb stick, however windows 8 still won't load.  Says it can't find the drive or the efi file.  Is grub not mounting the disk windows is installed on?**

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It seems the best answer is to use EasyBCD within VCplayer. Check out the link at the bottom. If that link doesn't work for you come back here and we'll solve it old school.

This is not a good fix, but as a work-around you can switch your bios settings to choose which hard drive you boot from. With one Linux hard drive and one windows hard drive that should ease the problem until you can fix it properly.

You need to update your bios. To dual boot Linux & win 8 you need to enable "Legacy boot" and/or disable "Secure boot". This option may not be available to you (yet) which is why I lead with the work around.

I will leave you with this one note. Check out these links: http://blog.hansenpartnership.com/linux-foundation-secure-boot-system-released/
http://www.zdnet.com/more-fun-with-windows-8-uefi-secure-boot-fedora-and-ubuntu-7000009292/
Edit: It seems there is a better answer than these. Goto [Dual boot windows 8 and Ubuntu with Windows 8 Boot manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager)