# How to get Windows 8 boot menu in a Windows 8-Ubuntu dual boot?

Tags: boot, 13.04, dual-boot, windows-8, easybcd

I have a dual-booted Windows 8-Ubuntu 13.04 system. As usual, by default, the Ubuntu grub menu comes up as soon as we boot. Similar questions have been asked before, and the reply to each of them was Grub Customiser and EasyBCD. My problem is that as soon as I restart my system, the changes in EasyBCD installer get reverted. Please provide me with a solution to this.

This is my boot-menu as in EasyBCD:

[image]

Now I go to the boot menu, set priority for Windows 8 the highest and in BCD deployment hit 'Write MBR'. Yet, when I restart, no changes take place and it reverts back to the same order.

Comment: Did you try the section "REPAIRING THE BOOT" from http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069

Comment: Actually, there isn't any problem with the boot, I just want the sky-blue Windows OS selection screen instead of the Purple Ubuntu one.

Comment: Wait, what you want is to install Ubuntu inside Windows (Hence the sky-blue selection screen) this is not going to happen any time soon. You can thank Microsoft for that and how difficult the Wubi installer handles Ubuntu on a Windows 8 computer. See the same answer I mentioned about Wubi (Which is what you are looking for) and why it does not work on Windows 8 pre-installed systems.

Comment: By previously asked questions I was referring to this
http://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager

Comment: in that case the user installed Ubuntu and Windows by himself (Not pre-installed so not in UEFI). The problem will still be there since Windows 8's boot manager is totally different than previous versions and it has brought more problems than solutions to a Dual-Boot system. If you did it as mentioned by the user that answered then you either have a hardware incompatibility or EasyBCD simply does not work with the current settings (Which amazes me taking into consideration the amount of problems I have encountered trying to boot both OS). I would suggest to ask in the EasyBCD Forums.

Comment: So that means the Ubuntu grub menu remains whatsoever we may try?

Comment: And by the way, does the grub-customiser also not work in UEFI?

Comment: it might. You simply have to try it with your current hardware and UEFI support. If Grub does not work as you have shown, then try EasyBCD. If that does not work then there may be other alternatives but I would stick with Grub using the Ubuntu installer or Grub-Repair and be on the safe side because, with all said and done, using Win8 + UEFI you will have a tougher time than creating a Dual-Boot system with a previous Win version. The grub-Customizer will work if you manage to install Grub correctly and dual boot both systems.

Comment: And 1 last question! If I were to format my hard disk completely and do everything in Legacy, is there a disadvantage?

Comment: The only one would be the time you will take to install everything again. In Legacy (Non-UEFI setup, No Windows 8 Pre-installed, Normal BIOS Setup) you will have the complete freedom as a normal computer should. In that case any boot manager like EasyBCD should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not gonna happen. I doubt that windows startup manager will see ubuntu partitions. It may but it will take you searching and playing around with settings. Rule of Thumb is : install windows first, install Linux after, allow Grub overwrite MBR and use grub. I guess this is not the answer you were looking for... ?

Comment: Actually, there is a way to do that. And as I said, there have been solutions to this previously, involving EasyBCD. Now my system doesn't accept the changes made by EasyBCD and reverts to default every time I boot.

Comment: @Ranveer It is impossible to find a solution to what you want. The only way for the boot to use the Windows style one (Even for EasyBCD) would be for you to remove Windows, disable UEFI and any other related EFI options and then install Windows 8 again followed by a Wubi installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: So has this been done in Legacy? 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager

Comment: @Ranveer Yes. OP there [says he's not using UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager#comment285695_231049).