# Dual boot windows 8 & ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-8

I have 3 partitions with windows 8 installed in the first one then i installed Ubuntu in the second one. By the end of the installation, my PC reboot on Ubuntu and doesn't show Windows8. So I run *boot repair*, but it gives me Windows Vista loader on `sda1` and when I click on it, it shows me a black screen.

[This the report of boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6173647/)

I've been looking over 8 hours for a solution and I looked up to every thread about this problem, but no one worked for me.

Comment: Heeeelp meeee plzzzz

Comment: Try to follow [these steps](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager).