# Dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows 8, Motherboard Settings inaccessible

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I have a Lenovo G580 with Windows 8 preinstalled with 1 Terabyte Hard Drive and 4Gb RAM.
 Now the thing is, I installed Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit version via a flash drive and status on the that moment was

1. Secure boot was enabled
2. UEFI mode enabled and I can't easily access my motherboard settings (big problem urgent help needed)

But after installing Ubuntu.. I could not access the motherboard settings because that option is gone (not showing) and the purple screen comes up when I boot showing options and windows boot manager gives some error there and only Ubuntu boots

I have tried boot repair but no progress

I think it has to do something with the grub configuration fi
le

so please tell me how to wipe out ubuntu completely to get back my original state where I could access my motherboard settings and then reinstall ubuntu

When I installed Ubuntu, I created `swap` area of 3Gb, `/home` partition of `12Gb and`/` root partition of 21Gb, and installed Ubuntu in root partition

Here is my boot repair output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6831351

Comment: Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) question or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager) question of any help?

Comment: "I can't easily access my motherboard settings (big problem urgent help needed)" Why can't you access it with an {F2} during boot? What is in the way?

Answer (score 0):

Most computers do give a way to access the firmware setup tools at boot time, but that method is often unprompted. Usually it's by pressing Del or a function key *before* GRUB appears, so try that. Shut down (don't reboot; it's often easier when starting cold) and try each of these keys.

If that fails, you may be able to get in from Windows, as described [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/20256-uefi-firmware-settings-boot-inside-windows-8-a.html) (among other places).

Several boot managers, such as [gummiboot](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gummiboot) and [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) provide a means to enter the firmware setup utility; but this feature doesn't work on all computers. Also, if your computer is set with Secure Boot active, you'll have to jump through some extra hoops to get either of those boot managers installed. See [the rEFInd Secure Boot documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) for details.