# Installed ubuntu for dual boot with windows 7, want to use windows bootmanager instead of grub

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

Installed ubuntu recently on to the same disk with windows 7.  Currently, grub loads and I've made windows the first choice so it loads into windows.  However, I want to use the windows bootmanager instead of grub.  I went into BIOS and changed the boot order, but that didn't seem to have any effect.  Where does one go to make this change?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager

Comment: I see what they did.  But I'd rather Windows just load without having it stop to ask.  I had it set up earlier this year, but I had no idea how to recreate it.  In essence, the computer boots like ubuntu isn't even installed and the only way to boot into it was hitting F8 during boot up and select ubuntu like I would select my dvd drive to boot from.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't believe this (Using BIOS boot menu to select) is possible if you only have one disk and that disk is MBR. The exception is if you are EFI booting.