# Recover Ubuntu boot loader after Windows 8.1 installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I've installed Windows 8.1 after Ubuntu 15. Now there is only one bootable OS and that is Windows 8.1. How can I recover Ubuntu 15 boot loader?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dual boot windows 8 and Ubuntu with Windows 8 Boot manager](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager)

Comment: Are both installed in UEFI boot mode or both installed in BIOS boot mode? And which boot mode is it?

Comment: I think this thread might http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows get you with some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `boot-repair`.

1. Create an Ubuntu LiveCD or LiveUSB
2. Boot into it.
3. Install the program `boot-repair` onto the CD or USB.
4. Launch Boot Repair and choose the default repair. It should work fine.

(There is also a more complex method available which involves chrooting into your system, but I personally prefer this one.)

This should work. Just ask if you need any more help :)

Answer (score 0):

### To recover Grub (I'm supposing this is the original bootloader)

- Boot through Fedora DVD or Red Hat DVD of Mandriva , **not** Ubuntu
- Select Troubleshooting and then select Rescue installed system option
- To the question "Do you want to start the networking" say no.

Once you get to the shell enter the following three commands:

1. `$chroot /mnt/sysimage`
2. `$cd /boot`
3. `$grub-install /dev/sda`

#### And you have your bootloader back ;-)

*Taken from [http://www.wikihow.com/Restore-Linux-Grub-After-Installing-Windows](http://www.wikihow.com/Restore-Linux-Grub-After-Installing-Windows_)*