# Dual Boot using Windows Bootloader instead of Grub

Tags: bootloader

I am using Windows 10 and now I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.... As my Laptop I have some problem using Grub Bootloader.

So, I followed this: [Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader) and follow every steps properly.

But still, I can run my Windows from bootloader and my ubuntu is not working from windows bootloader. I need to go BIOS setting to use Ubuntu !!

Still I can not use Ubuntu. I followed all the steps of EasyBCD

[image]

Comment: The case is totally different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual boot windows 8 and Ubuntu with Windows 8 Boot manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager)

Comment: Those tips not working

Comment: In Dual boot when I choose "Ubuntu", it shows following message which I upload

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the error messages you get when trying out the duplicates so we can give you more directed guidance.

Comment: What brand/model system? Are Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode or BIOS boot mode? EasyBCD does not work or work well with UEFI boot. And EasyBCd uses grub4dos which is based on the very old grub legacy, not grub2.

Comment: So, how can I update Grub? I am using Asus X450LN which is in Legacy Mode